# Validation error about Decimal data type in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I defined a data type `decimal(18,10)` for longitute and latitute in my database. But it always said *"validation error"*  when I tried to input and submit my form.
I used `LINQ to SQL`. Is there some validation rules it generated for me otherwise why I can not input these two with something numbers like "2.34".

Thanks in advance

```
namespace Nerddinner.Models
{
    interface IDinnerRepository
    {
        IQueryable<Dinner> FindAllDinners();
        Dinner GetDinner(int id);
        void AddDinner(Dinner dinner);
        void UpdateDinner(Dinner dinner);
        void DeleteDinner(Dinner dinner);
    }
}


namespace Nerddinner.Models
{
    public class sqlDinnerRepository: IDinnerRepository
    {
        dbDataContext db;
        public sqlDinnerRepository()
        {
            db = new dbDataContext();
        }

        public IQueryable<Dinner> FindAllDinners()
        {
            return db.Dinners;
        }

        public Dinner GetDinner(int id)
        {
            return db.Dinners.SingleOrDefault(x => x.DinnerID == id);
        }

        public void AddDinner(Dinner dinner)
        {
            db.Dinners.InsertOnSubmit(dinner);
        }

        public void UpdateDinner(Dinner dinner)
        {
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }

        public void DeleteDinner(Dinner dinner)
        {
            db.Dinners.DeleteOnSubmit(dinner);
        }
    }
}


namespace Nerddinner.Controllers
{
    public class DinnerController : Controller
    {
        IDinnerRepository _repository;
        public DinnerController()
        {
            _repository = new sqlDinnerRepository();
        }

        public DinnerController(IDinnerRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        //
        // GET: /Dinner/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var dinners = _repository.FindAllDinners();
            return View(dinners);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Dinner/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var dinner = _repository.GetDinner(id);
            return View(dinner);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Dinner/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        } 

        //
        // POST: /Dinner/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Dinner dinner)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                _repository.AddDinner(dinner);
                _repository.UpdateDinner(dinner);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View(dinner);
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Dinner/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var dinner = _repository.GetDinner(id);
            return View(dinner);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Dinner/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {

            var db = new dbDataContext();
            var dinner = db.Dinners.SingleOrDefault(x => x.DinnerID == id);
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here
                UpdateModel(dinner, collection.ToValueProvider());
                _repository.UpdateDinner(dinner);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View(dinner);
            }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Dinner/Delete/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var db = new dbDataContext();
            var dinner = db.Dinners.SingleOrDefault(x => x.DinnerID == id);
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here
                _repository.DeleteDinner(dinner);
                _repository.UpdateDinner(dinner);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View(dinner);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: please provide more information

Comment: It is a solution for finding dinner places. So the solution allows administratort to create dinner with "Longitude",  "Latitude", and "Description", etc. Everything works well except "Longitude" and "Latitude". I defined them as Decimal(18,10) in my database. And LINQ for my database model. When I tried to input these two in my form with some data like "9.432", it showed my error about"the inputed number is invalid".

Comment: Are you including any client-side code to format the textbox? like javascript used to format your decimal number like this: "485,388.50" ?

Answer (score 1):

In **ASP.NET MVC**, You can use the DisplayFormatAttribute on your model property:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.##}")]
public decimal decimalNumber { get; set; }
```

The above will output a number with up to 2 decimal places.
For more information visit: [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) and [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

**IN SQL SERVER:**
**decimal(m,a)**: m is the number of total digits your decimal can have, while a is the max number of decimal points you can have.

so if you put PI into a Decimal(18,0) it will be recorded as 3

if you put PI into a decimal(18,2) it will be recorded as 3.14

if you put PI into Decimal(18,10) be recorded as 3.1415926535

I think my answer will help you. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Dear, thanks for sharing the knowledge with me. But I use LINQ to SQL. No code for database.

Comment: Dear if you share your code where you are getting, we can help u. Only overall scenario can't help any of stackoverflow users.

Comment: Dear I already put my code. I hope it can make you guys understanding my solution. Thanks.