# decimal datafields throw validation error (ASP.Net MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

I have a question about (Clientside?) validation of datafields.

My model has a decimal property

```
public decimal CalculatedWork { get; set; }
```

If I try to insert a decimal value like 20,00 I get an error "Value has to be numeric".
If I insert 20, everything is fine and when refreshing, 20,00 is shown.

How can I get this work?
I tried [This DataFormatString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748628/validation-error-about-decimal-data-type-in-asp-net-mvc) and this [DecimalModelBinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698984/default-asp-net-mvc-3-model-binder-doesnt-bind-decimal-properties/5759788#5759788) but nothing works.

The DecimalModelBinder isn't even hit. 
What can I do or where is my fault?

Comment: you're using comma for the decimal point, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Meanwhile I found something for client side validation. It overwrites the validation in javascript. Sorry, didn't find it again.